# Fake authentication and authorization for testing asp.net core app

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, visual-studio-debugging, asp.net-authorization

I have a nuget package using minimal api like this:

```
 IEndpointRouter.MapGet("/somepath, (context) => handler(context))
    .RequireAuthorization("SomePolicy")
```

The idea is that whoever is installing the nuget package will have to implement that `SomePolicy` authorization and don't care what it is.

I just want to debug an asp.net app in Visual Studio.  Let's assume the `SomePolicy` is implementing JWT bearer token.  How can I fake the authentication and authorization in setup.cs. I don't want the app check the identity authority or anything at all. Is there a way I can setup the authorization in DI so that it returns true for `SomePolicy` without checking anything. May be something like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(policy => policy.AddPolicy("SomePolicy", x => true)).
```

If that's not possible, I can have the test client send a test JWT token in the Authorization header as `Bearer token`. I don't want this token validated for anything but want the authorization return a success response so `RequireAuthorization('SomePolicy')` passes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and seems to work:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("SomePolicy", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(ctx => true));
});
```